# GraphQL - limiting the number of subqueries to prevent Batching Attack

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I want to understand if there is a mechanism to limit the number of subqueries within the GraphQL query to mitigate against the GraphQL batching attack. (It's possible to send more than one mutation request per HTTP request because of the GraphQL batching feature)

Eg.

```js
{
    first: changeTheNumber(newNumber: 1) {
        theNumber
    }
    second: changeTheNumber(newNumber: 1) {
        theNumber
    }
    third: changeTheNumber(newNumber: 1) {
        theNumber
    }
}
```

I'm using `graphql-java-kickstart`.

Answer (score 0):

In `graphql-java` there are two [instrumentations](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/instrumentation/) that can check the "depth" or "complexity" or your query:

- [MaxQueryDepthInstrumentation](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/analysis/MaxQueryDepthInstrumentation.java)
- [MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/analysis/MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation.java)

The first one checks the depth of a query (how many levels are requests) the second one counts the fields. You can configure the expected max depth/complexity and if a query is deeper/complexer than your configured number it is rejected.
You can customize the behaviour of the `MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation` so that some fields count as "more complex" than others (for example you could say a plain string field is less complex than a field that requires it's own database request when processed).

[Here is an example](https://github.com/nilshartmann/spring-graphql-training/blob/main/app/publy-backend/src/main/java/nh/publy/backend/graphql/runtime/PublyGraphQLConfig.java#L63) that uses a custom direcive (`Complexity`) in a schema description to determine the complexity of a field.

If you only want to avoid that a concrete field is requested more than once, you could write you own `Instrumentation` or use the `DataFetchingEnvironment` in your resolver function to count the number of that fields in the current query (`getSelectionSet()` gives access to all fields contained in the current query).

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.